# Review queue flag description area is barely distinguishable from the question/answer area

Tags: feature-request, review

The only thing distinguishing the review queue description area from the question text is a box around it. Glancing at it, my eyes are not immediately drawn to the important part, which is the close reason, the flag, etc. Could we have a difference in text size, weight, or background color so that I don't have to keep finding it every time it moves to the next post in the queue? Even a thicker line for the box border would help.